# Predicting 5 next value based on sequence of numbers

Tags: python, lstm

I am trying to find a way to predict the next 5 numbers based on a sequence of numbers.

training set:

[image]

prediction:

[image]

I want to use LSTM to learn the training set to predict the next 5 numbers in the test set.
Do you have any idea how can I do this with LSTM?

Comment: Just to clarify: Does your entire training set consist of one sample/sequence? If that is the case, I am afraid training an LSTM will not be feasible due to the very limited amount of data.

Comment: Perhaps you meant to say "this is one sample from my training set:"

Comment: Have you tried the LSTM tutorials? This seems like a typical time-series prediction task. Try reusing some tutorial code on your dataset.

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution is to create a LSTM layer of 3 hidden states to learn.

Create sequence training set for LSTM from your data mentioned in the question, for example:

7 9 27 13 10 -> 60, will turn into these samples:
[7 9 27] -> 13
[9 27 13] -> 10
[27 13 10] -> 60

For a long input sequence, eg. [1 2 3 4 5 x1 x2 x3], with x1 x2 x3 are any last 3 values:

- Feed [x1 x2 x3] to the model to find x4
- Feed [x2 x3 x4] to the model to find x5
- Repeat again until you have enough predicted values, those'll be [x4 x5 x6 x7 x8]

Harder solution is to

- Create a LSTM layer with the number of hidden states of max_len(sequence).
- Pad those sequences not enough length by zeros
- Train the model with expected values on the right column

Inference:

- From input sequence, pad zeros to have enough length
- Feed to model
- Feed 5 times, after each feed, append the result to input sequence and get max_len items at tail to feed again

Comment: If only a unique number is allowed, it will be a problem with this solution, right?

Comment: u mean input of just 1 value? u can't predict with just 1 value, it's meaningless

Comment: I mean, what if we expect that Each number appears at most once in each sequence? if we try to predict the next number using the last 5 occurrences, this might happen: [X1,X2,X3,X4,X5] -> X6, [X2,X3,X4,X5,X6] -> X7 = X1

Comment: no u cant expect output to be a sequence of unique numbers, LSTM doesn't learn that objective